# Django Error 404 when navigating between two templates in an app

Tags: python, django, django-views, navigation

I have a Django (v3.2) project with several apps. One of these apps (manage_remittance - see below) offers a list of items in the database (template remittance_view.html), and on the top of the list, there is a link leading to a form (template remittance_add.html) supposed to be used for adding new items.

Here's the problem: I cannot navigate from remittance_view to remittance_add.
I have spent entire day on this, and there must be something fundamentally wrong (with the project setup?), but I fail to see, what exactly.

This is the error message I keep getting when I click on the link on the top of the list:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/manage_remittance/remittance_add.html

Using the URLconf defined in screentest_project.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
    admin/
    [name='login']
    login/ [name='login']
    logout/ [name='logout']
    manage_remittance/ [name='remittance_view']
    manage_remittance/ [name='remittance_add']
    manage_settings/
    export/
    entity_setup/
    ^static/(?P<path>.*)$
    ^media/(?P<path>.*)$

The current path, manage_remittance/remittance_add.html, didn’t match any of these
```

And, of course, I get the very same error message if type in a direct URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/manage_remittance/remittance_add.html
Same happens with http://127.0.0.1:8000/remittance_add.html and with http://127.0.0.1:8000/manage_remittance//manage_remittance/remittance_add.html

File remittance_add.html is present under templates (even in two directories - same file)

```
manage_remittance/templates/manage_remittance/remittance_add.html
manage_remittance/templates/remittance_add.html
```

remittance_view.html (the template from which I want to reach remittance_add.html, loop to display current values is not shown):

```
{% extends "root.html" %}
{#{% load static %}#}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{#{% url 'manage_remittance:remittance_add' as remittance_add %}#}
{% block scripts %}

{% endblock scripts %}

{% block title %}
View remittance data
{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}
{#xoxoxo {% url 'remittance_add' %} xoxoxo#}
<div class="list-group col-6">
<a href="remittance_add.html" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action shadow-mt list-group-flush list-group-item-dark text-light">Click here to add remittance data</a>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

manage_remittance: urls.py. 'remittance_add' is here, and it is also imported from manage_remittance/views.py:

```
from .views import (
    remittance_list,
    remittance_add,
)

app_name = 'manage_remittance'

urlpatterns = [
    path('',remittance_list,name='remittance_view'),
    path('remittance_add/',remittance_add, name='remittance_add')
    ]
```

manage_remittance: views.py. A view called 'remittance_add'  is here.

```
def remittance_list(request):
    rem_list = Remittance.objects.all()
    # print(rem_list)
    context = { 'rem_list': rem_list}
    return render(request,'remittance_view.html', context)

def remittance_add(request):
    print ('>>> REMITTANCE ADD INVOKED')
    return render (request, 'remittance_add.html')
```

Furthermore, I am using a navbar (placed at the project level) to navigate across all the various apps. By default I call remittance_view from the navbar:

I can replace remittance_view with remittance_add, and it works from the navbar:

```
{% url 'manage_remittance:remittance_add' as remittance_setup_page %}
```

But it does not work from the app itself.

remittance_add.html itself: (currently just displays some text and provides an OK button)

```
{% extends "root.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block scripts %}
{% endblock scripts %}

{% block title %}
add remittance data
{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}
<div class="col-6">
    <form action="" method="post">
    ADD REMITTANCE DATA: {{ request.user }}
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form | crispy }}
    <input type="submit" value="OK">
  </form>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: Templates have **no** relation whatsoever with Django's url router. If you are assuming that just because a template exists you can write a url like that then you are wrong.

Comment: Please see above, I have also configured the urls and the views.

Comment: Well I see no url pattern like `manage_remittance/remittance_add.html` so my point above stands...

Comment: I have set it up in urls.py by (`app_name = 'manage_remittance'`). Now, if I replace `path('manage_remittance/remittance_add/', remittance_add, name='remittance_add')` with a  `path('manage_remittance/remittance_add/', remittance_add, name='remittance_add')`, I still get error 404, but now Django is looking against `manage_remittance/ manage_remittance/remittance_add/ [name='remittance_add']`. How did you mean no url pattern?

Comment: `manage_remittance/remittance_add/` is not the same as `manage_remittance/remittance_add.html`...

Comment: Are you now referring to the path in urlpatterns in urls.py? I am sorry for asking such a question, but I am completely confused at this point.

Comment: The paths configured in the urlpatterns are the only paths Django will recognize... so yes I am talking about them.

Comment: path('remittance_add.html', remittance_add, name='remittance_add')

Comment: Thank you! I had missed this one, and then I wasted several hours on trying to find what is wrong, and did not notice this! Many thanks!